# how to make this in react js select with view option

Tags: html, reactjs

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOmis.png)

How can I make this in `ReactJS` view option not like select and option.

form html:

```
<form>
  <div className="form1">
   <div className="flex-item1">
      <select name="type"  className="CodesSelect3">
        <option  value="Drug">ProviderID</option>
      </select>
    </div >
    <div className="flex-item2" > 
      <select name="type"  className="CodesSelect3">
        <option  value="Drug">Network</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div className="flex-item4">
      <input type="submit"  value="Save" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="form1">
    <div className="flex-item1">
      <select name="type"  className="CodesSelect3">
        <option  value="Drug">Policy</option>
      </select>
    </div >
    <div className="flex-item2" > 
      <select name="type"  className="CodesSelect3">
        <option  value="Drug">Member</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div className="flex-item5">
      <input type="submit"  value="Edit" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="form1">
    <label className="flex-item1" >
      Frequency Utilization:
    </label>
    <input type="text" className="flex-item2" name="name" />
    <div className="flex-item6">
      <input type="submit"  value="Delete" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="form1">
    <label className="flex-item1" >
      Service Utilization:
    </label>
    <input type="text" className="flex-item2" name="name" />
    <div className="flex-item3" > 
      <select name="type"  className="CodesSelect3">
        <option  value="Drug">Monthly</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="form1">
    <label className="flex-item1" >
      Age
    </label>
    <input type="text" className="flex-item2" name="name" />
    <div className="flex-item3" > 
      <select name="type"  className="CodesSelect3">
        <option  value="Drug">Gender</option>
      </select>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div className="form1">
    <label className="flex-item1" >
      Age
    </label>
    <input type="text" className="flex-item2" name="name" />
    <div className="flex-item3" > 
      <select name="type"  className="CodesSelect3">
        <option  value="Drug">Gender</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: see the image..

Answer (score 0):

[Choice Group](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/choicegroup)

you can use Fluient Ui that gives Choice group the close one for the one you want to display and use.